# Replacement for C-style loop in Swift 2.2 CGFloat

Tags: for-loop, swift2

I have tried this with CGFloat and i am getting the following error: Can not invoke stride with an argument list of type '(CGFloat by: CGFloat)'

```
for var min:CGFloat = 0.0; min<=45.0; min = min+value {

print("\(min)")
}
```

to:

```
for min:CGFloat in 0.stride(CGFloat(55.0), by: min+value) {

   print("\(min)")
}
```

Comment: How about `(0.0).stride(55.0, by: value)`?

Comment: Since my delve into Swift was writing school code rather than production code, I just converted to `while` loops rather than bothering to learn the asinine syntax for a "proper" Swift `for`: `var min:CGFloat = 0.0; while(min <= 45.0){ /*...;*/ min+=value; }` Might be something to consider doing if that's your use case haha

Comment: ty abluejelly, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the latest overload for stride. You can use cast the number to CGFloat for the stride.

```
for min in (0 as CGFloat).stride(to: 55, by: value) {
    print("\(min)")
}
```

However, stride returns a Striable when the for-loop begin. The `by` value does not update with the iteration of for-loop. A while-loop would be better for this case,

```
var min : CGFloat = 0

while (min < 55) {
    print("\(min)")
    min += value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
let toValue = CGFloat(10.0)
let distance = CGFloat(3.3)


// stride in interval from 0.0 ..< 10.0, with distance 3.3

let sequence = fromValue.stride(to: toValue, by: distance)
print(sequence.dynamicType)
/*
 StrideTo<CGFloat>
 */

// StrideTo conforms to SequenceType protocol, so we can use for-in
for element in sequence {
    print("\(element)")
}
/*
 0.0
 3.3
 6.3
 9.9
*/
```

Comment: ty, but i am trying to use an arithmetic operator in the stride (by: parameter), is that not supported?

Comment: @cmarti1138 using `by: min+value` is not what you intended.  You simply want `by: value`.